# Issues using ConvertTimeZone in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

***Inside Logic App:***

In my set variable of type string, I am trying to use the following expression. What is the problem here? I get the following error message. The same expression works perfectly for setting the filename in my create blob action.

**formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','GMT Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd')**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could see that the mentioned expression was working fine. Instead of using `formatDateTime` and  `convertTimeZone` separately, According to `convertTimeZone` syntax you can directly use the required format within `convertTimeZone` itself. Below is the complete expression that will work.

```
convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','GMT Standard Time','yyyy-MM-dd')
```

According to the [Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11), the GMT Standard Time and UTC are in the same timezone and doesn't have any time difference. If that's the case you can use only `formatDateTime` and format the date time in required format.

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

Result :

[image]